# ASP.Net C#, Is it possible to filter a Listview based on a DropDownList?

Tags: c#, asp.net

New to ASP.Net web forms(what is currently used in my shop) and C#.  Is it possible to filter a Listview based on a DropDownList?  If so, how, or what do I need to learn?

I'd like to be able to select the SchoolChoiceType Name (#1) and it would only show those selected (#2).

[image]

**My overall goal:**  My goal is to filter the SchoolChoiceType name to pull up the list of students I want to work on.  Once the list is filtered, I would like to click on the student and that pop out a screen where I can edit information on that particular student.  I'm new and I don't even know what to call that pop-out screen, or where to start on how to program it.

I figured one of the best ways to learn is to get in and do what I'm trying to accomplish.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: yeah it's possible. but what did you try? :) did you do some research?

Comment: Bet, there are plenty of tutorials on web that shows how to do it. What does exactly does not work for you? If you want to filter this on server-side - pass value of this combobox to server and filter data there. If the data is not too big you can use JS - just type in google jquery filter table.

Comment: okay. could you please give us more info? are you using a framework or is this pure ASP.Net, HTML and CSS? What library or better, namespcae/type is your table? Is this the default WebForms? e.g. `Grid`?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to bind the list in the "onselectedindexchanged" event of dropdownlist. In this function just apply the condition on the datasource which you are binding to the listview based on the value selected in the dropdown and then bind it with the listview. It will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pretty much any input control to filter an anything using any property it possesses.   DropDownLists and Comboboxes are very common for this purpose.

Without sample code (which we prefer you post 'round these parts with your question), I can tell you that most of these controls have three properties you can use for this.

-`SelectedText`  = The displayed text of your selection

-`SelectedValue` = The value represented by your selection

-`SelectedIndex` = The 0-based index of the selection among the available choices

You'll use these values in combination with the `onSelectedIndexChanged` event or similar (each has its respective event with the same naming convention).  Alternatively, you can use `IsPostBack` in your codebehind file to read these values and update the query that creates the grid, but you'll need to set the DropDownList/ComboBox's `AutoPostBack` property to `true`.

You will also want to wrap the grid in some sort of Ajax panel so the whole page doesn't refresh just to update the grid.  Otherwise, it'll either do nothing  or blink the whole page at the user like it's 1999, depending on your approach.